# How to convert mysql query to query builder for laravel 5?

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, query-builder, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to get all duplicates rows from **Customers** Table
I want to convert the following mysql query into query builder to use in laravel 5. And I search in documentation but  not luck.

```
SELECT 
   CustomerName, 
   ContactName, 
   Customers.City 
FROM 
   Customers
INNER JOIN(
            SELECT 
               City 
            FROM Customers 
            GROUP BY City 
            HAVING COUNT(CustomerName) >1 ) temp 
ON Customers.City = temp.City;
```

and here I search in google and tried like this , but this query builder is just showing only one row if duplicate.I just want every rows which are duplicates.

```
> $duplicates = DB::table('customers')
->select('CustomerName','City', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as `count`'))
->groupBy('CustomerName', 'City')
->having('count', '>', 1)
->get();
```

Any help you have would be greatly appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel supports subqueries in `whereIn`.

```
$subQuery = DB::table('Customers')
    ->select('City')
    ->groupBy('City')
    ->havingRaw('count(*) > 1');

$duplicates = DB::table('Customers')
    ->select('CustomerName','City')
    ->whereIn('City', $subquery)
    ->get();
```

This will not create the same query. But will return the same result.

Answer (score 0):

just remove the groupBy that is mergin the query